Photoshop what determines whether the printer (HP Photosmart 7520) uses photo black or regular black?
I have an HP Photosmart 7520 that I use as my "everything" printer. I never used it for printing Photos, but I'm getting older now and thought maybe it would be nice to have a few Photos.
Normally I just put in Magenta-Blue-Yellow-Cyan, and I print a lot of flyers for work, so I use offbrand ink I buy on amazon and its actually really cheap. I thought about getting an ecotank, but I can't see buying a $200 printer to save on ink when I spend only about $100/yr on ink. Plus the Photosmart has a feed scanner, which is useful for scanning legal work. I don't really have a spot to have one printer for printing and one printer for scanning, so I think I'm just going to run my Photosmart until it breaks or they stop making ink for it.
My question, how can I tell whether the printer is using Photo black or Black? Does it just use Photo black when I set the paper type to "Photo X" (eg: Photo Glossy, Photo Matte, ect)?
Does it matter whether the quality is set to normal or best?

Your title is about Photoshop, but do you mean about Photosmart printer? Please edit the title and/or question to clarify that.

As you assumed, and HP states

When Plain paper is selected, the ordinary black ink is used.
When one of the Photo papers is selected, photo black ink is used.

Notes on the comment to use the printer until it stops working.

After a certain number of pages, a printer may stop because an internal counter needs to be reset, such as that for the waste ink absorber. There are online resources such as this video that shows how to access a hidden menu to reset counters.
HP has been updating printers to disable them if one cartridge is dry or if a non-HP cartridge is used. Once that happens, it might be time to consider an "ecotank" printer that is ink-agnostic.

